# For given problem if we change the setting what will happen?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, analytic-continuation

I encountered following problem [image]

and I solved it by using the hint provided. Thinking of it I noticed 
that I am able to solve it even if I use the following function:
$$
F(z)=1/f(1/z)),\quad |z|> 1$$
$$ =f(z) ,      \quad |z|\leq 1
$$

What is the problem if I use this function to solve the problem? I can extend it to the whole $\mathbb{C}$ as well: I know that analytic continuation of any function is unique, but I am thinking where is problem if I choose to use this function.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To be continuous on unit circle.** when $|z|=1$ then $\bar{z}=\dfrac{1}{z}$ therefore
on unit circle
$$\dfrac{1}{\overline{f(1/\bar{z})}}=\dfrac{1}{\overline{f(z)}}=f(z)$$
with definition $f(z)$ in $|z|<1$ and $\dfrac{1}{\overline{f(1/\bar{z})}}$ in $|z|>1$. in your case this continuation will not be continouess.

Comment: Ohh THanks a lot Sir. Is it possible to show Function that was given by me is not continuous ?

Comment: Your assertion valid if $f(1/z)=1/f(z)$ where $z=e^{it}$. is it hold? in your case we have to $f(e^{-it})f(e^{it})=1$